# Asynchronous error on SmtpClient SendMailAsync in http handler (ashx)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sendmail

I've been running a C# http handler (ashx) to send mail for years.  We believe the problem started when we switched to 4.5.1.  We are getting the error:

"An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle..."

I was using:

```
public static void sendMessage(....
...
client.SendAsync(message);
```

After looking around for what was happening, the method was changed to:

```
public static async Task sendMessage(....
...
await client.SendMailAsync(message);
```

I'm assuming that we still get this error because not all the calls up the stack have the async operator.  To do that, I'd have to make the entire handler, that does many other things, asynchronous which doesn't sound like a good idea just to send mail.

So, I have two questions:

1. Am I correct in that I'm not using async in every method that eventually calls sendMessage?
2. How do I send mail asynchronously now?

Comment: I looked at the link but it restates what I've already done.  The problem is both asynchronous options produce the error.

Comment: If you're referring to Page, an http handler (ashx) doesn't fit.

Comment: Can anyone advise me on question #1 above?... #2 as well?

Comment: Would a reasonable approach be to simply start a new thread and have the thread send the email synchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were no more comments, I just started a new thread and sent the message synchronously.  Seems to work fine, haven't had a problem since.